# How can I implement share in navigation layout

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an navigation app and I want to make share item work I used this code but it does not work

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_download) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_favorite) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_allstories) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        id.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                myIntent.setType("text/plain");
                String shareBody="Your Body Here";
                String shareSub="Your Subject Here";
                myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,shareSub);
                myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,shareBody);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent,"Share using"));

            }
        });

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

I do not know how can I reach to the item.
I also tried `ShareView` but I think the android does not supported or something like this.

Comment: When you click on the item `onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)` is called?

Comment: You don't need `clickListener` inside `onNavigationItemSelected` remove it, and if you doing every thing correctly it will work.

Comment: You may want to learn about switch/case construct.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_download) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_favorite) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_allstories) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        myIntent.setType("text/plain");
        String shareBody="Your Body Here";
        String shareSub="Your Subject Here";
        myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,shareSub);
        myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,shareBody);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent,"Share using"));

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```